# How to change PDF version output in pdftocairo?

Tags: pdf, poppler

Command `pdftocairo` is an utility from [poppler-utils](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/poppler-utils) package. It's a PDF to PNG/JPEG/PDF/PS/EPS/SVG converter using [Cairo](https://cairographics.org). I use this command to update a very old PDF from version 1.2 to 1.5, for example:

```bash
$ pdftocairo -pdf input.pdf output.pdf
```

The PDF version of the output PDF in my system is always 1.5:

- Linux Mint 21.1
- poppler-utils 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1
- cairo 1.16.0

**My questions:**

**1)** Is possible to convert to a higher PDF version? Like 1.7?

**2)** There is ANY advantage in update a PDF version?

> **PS.:** I have opened an issue in [Gitlab's Poppler](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/1411).